# Mysql "order of operations" Question

Tags: sql, mysql, select

Here's my situation: I want to SELECT all entries from a database WHERE id = $id.  But I want the results to be listed in a certain priority.  If, criteria = $criteria, then I want those results displayed first.  Otherwise, I just want to keep displaying the rest of the rows.

My question is this: will this solve my problem?

```
SELECT field1 WHERE (criteria=$criteria AND id = $id) OR id=$id  LIMIT 5
```

Will the query look at the () first? If not, is there another way to do this without splitting this into two separate queries?

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT  field1
FROM    mytable
WHERE   id = $id
ORDER BY
        criteria = $criteria DESC, id
LIMIT 5
```

, or this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  field1
        FROM    mytable
        WHERE   id = $id
                AND criteria = $criteria
        ORDER BY
                id
        LIMIT 5
        ) q
UNION
FROM    (
        SELECT  field1
        FROM    mytable
        WHERE   id = $id
        ORDER BY
                id
        LIMIT 5
        ) q2
ORDER BY
        criteria = $criteria DESC, id
LIMIT 5
```

The latter is more efficient if you have an index on `(id, criteria)` (in this order).

Comment: +1: This is how I'd do it.  Strangely, you can't do this sort of thing in Oracle without a subquery because Oracle's way of doing it (rownumber) is applied before the order by.

Comment: Does the location of DESC matter?
I want the criteria first, in terms of highest id to lowest id.

Should it be criteria = $criteria, id DESC instead?

Comment: @Michael: if you want highest `id`'s first, use `ORDER BY criteria = $criteria DESC, id DESC`

Comment: Thanks, then what does the DESC in criteria = $criteria DESC do as opposed to criteria = $criteria

Comment: @Michael: it will first select rows with `$criteria` (from highest to lowest `id`), then all other rows (again, from highest to lowest `id`)

Comment: @Michael: `criteria = $criteria DESC` is a boolean expression. `TRUE` are `1` and `FALSE` are `0`. `DESC` makes `TRUE` values come first.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT field1
  FROM mytable
 WHERE id = $id
 ORDER BY CASE WHEN criteria = $criteria THEN 0 ELSE 1 END CASE
 LIMIT 5;
```

This will list rows matching the criteria before those not because zero comes before one.

If this won't work directly - as written - then put the info into a sub-query:

```
SELECT field1
  FROM (SELECT field1,
               CASE WHEN criteria = $criteria THEN 0 ELSE 1 END CASE AS ordering
          FROM mytable
         WHERE id = $id
       ) AS subqry
 ORDER BY ordering
 LIMIT 5;
```

Often, there will be other secondary criteria to determine the order of rows within the 0 vs 1 ordering.

Answer (score -1):

Not related to the original question, just to clarify: operator AND have higher priority than OR hence why a or b and c or d is equal to a or (b and c) or d

Comment: If it is not related please do not post it.